# Any Way to send custom IR codes in the Sony Android IR SDK

Tags: android, sony, infrared

I've downloaded the Sony Android Add-on IR SDK (http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk/ir-remote-api/) and it appears that you can only send "learned" commands and/or built in commands from the built in device list.   Am I missing something or Is there a way to actually send my own custom IR commands so I can control devices that aren't in the built in database and I don't have to force the end user to "learn" the codes from a remote control device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible as it says in the documentation: "The transmission of a signal for devices that are NOT registered on Sony’s IR remote control app is NOT supported."

Comment: Thanks -- I missed that line in the docs.  That is exactly what I was afraid of.   The recent Samsung devices & HTC One allow full control, which makes the Sony quite a poor choice for any of the IR apps I'm working on.   Oh well, maybe Sony will fix it later.